# NSIS Skip pages at runtime

Tags: nsis

My installer is checking if the program is already installed and I would like to skip the "Enter the path" page in that case.

How can I script that in NSIS 2.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To skip a page, call the [abort](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.4.1) instruction in the [pre callback function](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.5.3) for that page

Comment: The pre callback function exists only in the Page function which I'm a bit relunctant to use since they do not seem to include normal headers. I prefer the "!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES" function (which have the right headers in the right language).

Comment: @Silence: You forgot to mention that you are using the MUI. You need to use the MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE define when using MUI pages.

Comment: Both your solutions works but I prefer the second one. Thank you !

Comment: When I use Abort in MUI in _PRE function for MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY all Sections are executed twice? Is there something special for this page?

Comment: @Slappy: That does not sound right, maybe post a new question with a minimal example?